# How can I speed up a query that fetches a single object from multiple tables?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, performance, entity-framework

How can I speed up a query that fetches multiple objects based on keys?

For instance (forgive my contrived example), say I have multiple tables **Paper**, **Document**, and **File** in SQL Server. Each file record has one document "parent" and each document record has one paper "parent". A paper could have multiple documents, and therefore eventually multiple files associated with the paper.

**Paper Table**

---

```
int Paper_Key - PK

varchar Paper_Name
```

---

**Document Table**

---

```
int Document_Key - PK

int Paper_Key

varchar Doc_Name
```

---

**File Table**

---

```
int File_Key - PK

int Document_Key
```

From the file level, say we want to retrieve both the document and the paper associated with with a particular file (there are millions of rows in all of these tables).

My initial thoughts are to use my Unit of Work pattern with my generic repository and retrieving each record sequentially by the keys.

**Service Method**

```
public MyViewModel GetFileWithDetails(int fileId)
{
    File file = _unitOfWork.FileRepository.GetById(fileId);
    Document doc = _unitOfWork.DocumentRepository.GetById(file.Document_Key);
    Paper paper = _unitOfWork.PaperRepository.GetById(doc.Paper_Key);

    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        FileKey = file.File_Key,
        // etc etc
    }

    return model;
}
```

**Generic Repository Method**

```
internal MyDBEntities context;
internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

public GenericRepository(MyDBEntities context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}

public TEntity GetById(object id)
{
    return dbSet.Find(id);
}
```

Would there be any way to execute this query faster? I am using the same pattern for most of the other pages (details, lists), but selecting from multiple tables seems to take an exponential more amount of time - especially since each query has to wait for the result of the previous to be able to execute.

**EDIT**
There are not relationships between the tables, unfortunately. Only the keys. I requested for relationships to be drawn but SQL will not allow due to null values or something.....I am not in charge of the tables.

Comment: Try to add indexes to the referential keys and then rebuild the indices to see some performance improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute a single query joining multiple tables using the [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eager) method.

Nobody says a repository can't take other data types into account, just choose the central object and put the method in a repository that inherits your generic base repository.

Comment: There are no relationships drawn in the database, it is currently only using keys. That was my first wish, but the IT guy in charge can not draw relationships between the tables for some reason.

Comment: If you don't have actual relationships, that's probably a large part of your problem.

Comment: I agree, I have been requesting them for months now and have tried to explain not having the relationships is causing the speed issues. So for now I am trying to find any other way to make it more efficient.

Comment: @Cody Relationships are not really required, they only facilitate. You can alway (and should) use joins. It's more important to know whether all relevant indexes exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.Include` to bring back the related entities.